# Пропускная способность удаленного сервера

Tags: сервер, сеть, curl

Скачиваю картинки с серверов клиентов по их согласию. 5 000 - 20 000 Использую cURL multy - из за чего повисал сайт, ограничил одновременные запросы до 20 за раз. Это решение считаю костылем, так как никогда не известно - может попасться сервер у которого пропускная способность меньше. Подскажите - есть ли запрос к серверу - чтобы узнать какое максимальное количество соединений он готов обработать за раз, чтобы не перегружая его отправить ему 70% запросов за раз от его максимально допустимой.

Comment: Нету, так как число одновременно обрабатываемых запросов может быть теоретически неограниченным, лишь оперативки со свопом хватило и соответствующие лимиты в ядре и настройках веб-серверов подняты (но даже лимиты по умолчанию намного больше этих ваших 20 запросов)

Comment: Нет. К тому же эта характеристика у сервера может "плавать". Ну и вполне может быть ситуация, что сервер, может, и отдал бы, но канал не позволяет (причём пропускная способность канала - тоже ни фига не константа). Так что только экспериментально, для каждого сервера отдельно - скажем, увеличить на 10%, подождать, посмотреть, если всё нормально, повторить, если стало ненормально, откатиться на 20% и успокоиться.

Comment: Хотя вообще могут существовать какие-нибудь искусственные ограничения, например по числу запущенных админом процессов apache2 или php-fpm. Но каких-то публично доступных способов узнать такие лимиты вроде всё равно не делают (хотя бы потому, что это сильно помогло бы организациям (D)DoS-атак), так что тут только у админа спрашивать, где какие лимиты он настроил. Ну или экспериментально подбирать, как Akina выше предлагает